# Rails - How to store one frequently changing string persistently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am consuming an API once a day. The root resource is a ordered list of IDs, **without** any other attributes like "created_at" or "updated_on".

I need to remember which IDs I already processed. Currently I am storing the last ID in a file which is a viable solution but it seems a bit odd.

Using the database for only one ID is way too much.

I can't look into my database if a record with the ID is already there, since processing an ID from the API can include ingoring the ID and move on to the next one.

The solution I am looking for needs to be persistent even if I restart the server/application or if I move the whole application. It's fine if it's a Rails only solution. Is there anything better than using a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we did in the end:

Since storing it in a file has some disadvantages we decided to take a completely different approach. Another reason why we didn't want to save the latest id is that we don't want to rely on the API, what if the order of the ids changes?

We therefore created a database table and inserted every id, we then mark an id as processed. With this approach we do not have to save the "latest id", we always compare all available ids with all ids in our database to check which ids are not yet processed.

Comment: Yep, this is more robust than storing just last processed id.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last ID in a text file. Provided it's in a directory that is flagged in .gitignore it should persist through redeployment, etc. You may also want to include the environment in the file name.

Write with...

```
File.open("#{Rails.env}_last_id.txt", 'w') { |f| f << current_last_id }
```

Read with...

```
previous_last_id = File.read("#{Rails.env}_last_id.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for YAML::Store. A little better than reading/writing to plain file, because you can use transactions.